# “Get product X for free on orders over $100” coupon code in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, discounts

Is there any simple way or any plugin around that allows to create a coupon code for the following kind of offer: "get product X for free on orders over $100"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible with an additional plugin: The commercial version of [WooCommerce Extended Coupon Features](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-added-coupons/).

- In WooCommerce coupons settings you have already a minimum field for orders amount:

[image: Minimun amount spend]

- The [free version of this plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-added-coupons/) has already **Auto coupons** functionality, which allow coupons to be **automatically added to the users cart** if it's restrictions are met. Also above
- With the [inexpensive commercial version of this plugin](http://www.soft79.nl/product/woocommerce-extended-coupon-features/) you have the missing functionality you need: **Adding free products** to the customer's cart based the on coupon rules.

So with that 3 functionalities, the conditions are met to auto add a coupon code for "get product X for free on orders over $100".

---

**Additional tricks about woocommerce coupons**

1) WooThemes snippet: [Create a coupon programmatically](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/)

2) Auto apply Discount Coupon to Customer’s Purchase:

```
function order_price_is_greater_than_100() {

    global $woocommerce, $total_qty;

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() >= 100 ) {

        $coupon_code = 'UNIQUECODE'; // <= set the name of your coupon code here

        if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount( sanitize_text_field( $coupon_code ))) {
            $woocommerce->show_messages();
        }

        echo '<div class="woocommerce_message"><strong>The total price in your cart is greater than 100: You get … </strong></div>';

    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'order_price_is_greater_than_100', 10, 0);
```